# Absolute value of a measurable function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X , \mathscr{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Prove that if $f$ is measurable, then $|f|$ is measurable.

- A function $f$ is *measurable* if $f^{-1}((a , \infty)) = \{x : f(x) > a\} \in \mathscr{M}$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Ok so this is what I have so far:

Consider two cases: $a < 0$ and $a \geq 0$. If $a < 0$, then we have $$|f|^{-1}((a , \infty)) = \{x : |f(x)| > a \} = X \in \mathscr{M}$$ since $\mathscr{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. I am confused on how to prove the case when $a \geq 0$. If $a \geq 0$, we have $$|f|^{-1}((a , \infty)) = \{x : |f(x)| > a \} = ?$$ I am assuming we will have to use that fact that $f$ is measurable. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Ok so in either case, it would follow that $\{x : |f(x)| > a\} \in \mathscr{M}$ since $f$ is measurable.

Comment: If we kept the cases as $a <0$ and $a \geq 0$ then for the case $a \geq 0$, we get $$|f|^{-1}((a , \infty)) = \{x : f(x) \geq a\} \cup \{x : f(x) \leq -a\} = f^{-1}([a , \infty)) \cup f^{-1}((-\infty , -a]).$$ But since $f$ is measurable it follows that the sets $\{x : f(x) > a\}$, $\{x : f(x) \geq a\}$, $\{x : f(x) < a\}$, and $\{x : f(x) \leq a\}$ are all equivalent correct? So we can leave the cases as is.

Comment: If $a \leq 0$, then I don't think we can say $$|f|^{-1}((a , \infty)) = \{x : |f(x)| > a \} = X$$ since $|f(x)|$ could equal zero.

Comment: How is it the empty set? I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For every $a\in\Bbb R$, we know that 
$$|f|^{-1}((a,\infty))=\{x:|f(x)|>a\}.$$ Hence, we get
$$|f|^{-1}((a,\infty))=
\begin{cases}
X,& \text{ if } a<0\\
f^{-1}((a,\infty))\cup f^{-1}((-\infty,-a)),&\text{ if }a\geq 0. 
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $X\in\mathscr{M}$. Because $f$ is a measurable function, it follows that  $f^{-1}((a,\infty)), f^{-1}((-\infty,-a))\in\mathscr{M}$ and hence, $$f^{-1}((a,\infty))\cup f^{-1}((-\infty,-a))\in\mathscr{M}.$$
Hope you are satisfied.

Comment: Maybe I am reading this wrong but since $|f(x)| \geq 0$ for all $x \in X$, if $a < 0$, wouldn't $\{x : |f(x)| > a\} = X$?

Comment: Yes I will edit my answer---)

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help! I am more than satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

> **Proposition 0.** Suppose $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measureable, and that $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measureable. Then so too is $g \circ f$.

*Proof.* Consider $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $A$ Borel-measureable. Then $g^{-1}(A)$ is Borel-measureable. Hence $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(A))$ is measureable. Hence $(g \circ f)(A)$ is measureable. We deduce that $g \circ f$ is measurable.

So, it remains to prove:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the absolute value function. Then $g$ is measurable.
>
> (Once again, all copies of $\mathbb{R}$ are viewed as measureable spaces with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in this theorem.)

*Proof.* Observe that:

$$g^{-1}(a,\infty) = (-\infty,-a)\cup (a,\infty)$$

So $g^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is clearly Borel-measurable. Hence $g$ is measurable.

Comment: I think your proposition 0 is wrong. Because there are measurable functions whose compositions is not measurable. For example if f be the Cantor lebesgue function and g=f(x)+x then this is a strictly increasing continuous function defined on [o,1] onto [0,2]. Now if we extend this to R continuously and keeping strictly increasing then it's inverse is continuous and measurable. Now g maps a measurable set A to a nonmeasurable set g(A). Now the characteristic function k of A is measurable. But k⁰g^-1 is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

$$\{x:|f(x)|\gt a\}=\{x:f(x)\gt a\}\cup\left(\mathbb R\setminus\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{x:f(x)\gt-a-\frac1n\}\right)$$